# java: проблема с односвязным списком

Tags: java

```
public class List {

    Node head = null;

    public void add(int value) {

        Node element = new Node(value);
        Node walker = head;
        while (walker != null) {
            walker = walker.next;

        }
        while (head == null) {
            head = element;
        }
    }
    public Integer getSize() {
        int size = 0;
        Node walker = head;
        while (walker != null) {
            walker = walker.next;
            size++;
            System.out.println(size);
        }
        return size;
    }

    public void print() {
        Node walker = head;
        while (walker != null) {
            System.out.println(walker.value);
            walker = walker.next;
        }

    }
}
```

Не правильно я написал метод add так как добавляет только первый елемент.
Можете подсказать в чем именно проблема?
Спасибо)

Comment: Возьми и исправь. Не за что)

Comment: Вы вообще не понимаете, что это делает - `while (walker != null) { walker = walker.next; }`?

Comment: Перебираем елементы и ищем последний

Comment: Нет, так мы последний элемент не найдем. Почему?

Comment: 'while (head == null) {
            head = element;
        }'
могу предположить что из за этого цикла

Comment: Нет, не из-за этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void add(int value) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(value);
    } else {
        Node walker = head;
        while (walker.next != null) {
            walker = walker.next;
        }
        walker.next = new Node(value);
    } 
}
```

Comment: `walker = element;` - wtf?

Comment: Лучше не стало.

Comment: @Igor спасибо! что-то я совсем напутал))  а так?)

Comment: Стало лучше. Но с этой проверки надо начинать.

Comment: @Igor согласен. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, вроде исправил.

Comment: Да, только теперь не нужна первая проверка `(walker != null)` в `while`.

Comment: `if (head == null) {
  head = new Node(value);
} else {
  Node walker = head;
  while (walker.next != null) {
    walker = walker.next;
  }
  walker.next = new Node(value);
}
`

Comment: Поправил, спасибо